# SPLinq and PeoplePicker

Tags: linq

I have a List where one of its field is based on the People Editor control. The field name is Organizer. How do I get the value if this field using SPlinq.
When I iterate thru the list item in debug mode, I can see that the OrganizerImnName has a value. And in the intellisense of the SPLinq I can see this two attributes, OrganizerId and OrganizerImnName.
When I try to get the value Like this

```
var results = from o in dc.GetList<OrganizerItem>("Organizer")
select new { Organizer =  o.OrganizerImnName };
```

I get this error ***The query uses unsupported elements, such as references to more than one list, or the projection of a complete entity by using EntityRef/EntitySet.***

Answer (score 1):

This error means that o.OrganizerImnName (sp?) is a complex type, so you need to specify a property of that value, such as Title. Use Intellisense to see what properties are available.

You could also try: `select new { Organizer =  o.OrganizerItem.Title };`

Comment: Thanks Laurie. .ToList() solved my problem. You can find more here http://xpressivecode.com/blog/post/2011/04/19/Error-The-query-uses-unsupported-elements-such-as-references-to-more-than-one-list-or-the-projection-of-a-complete-entity-by-using-EntityRefEntitySet.aspx